# Eithad preclearance at Abu Dhabi, landing at JFK, connecting flight at LGA and checked in baggage

Tags: luggage, airport-transfer, connecting-flights, jfk, lga

I'll be doing US customs preclearance at Abu Dhabi airport and landing at JFK airport. But my connecting flight is at LGA. Do I have to claim my checked in luggage at JFK and then recheck it at LGA or will the luggage go straight to my domestic airport?

Also flight lands at 4:30pm. Is 4.5 hours enough to get to LGA?

Whats the best mode of transportation to LGA from JFK?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Travel.SE. Please ask only one question at a time, and please indicate what research you have already attempted (for example, do you find the [airport connections](http://www.panynj.gov/airports/jfk-airport-connections.html) page on the JFK website unsatisfactory?); the [site tour](http://travel.stackexchange.com/tour) will explain better how this site operates. The "best" mode depends on whether you value time, or money, or adventure the most, and at what point you decide a tradeoff is or isn't worth it, but yes, 4½ hours should be enough time to connect, even with reclaiming bags.

Comment: Sorry about that. Anyways my major concern is do I have to claim the baggage and recheck at LGA?

Comment: I googled about this and most people say they do not have to claim and recheck, but their connecting flight is at the same airport.

Comment: As you're changing airports, you will have to claim your bags, carry them with you, and re-check them at LGA. Through-checking with pre-Clearance only works if it's the same airport

Answer (score 1):

Yes you will need to collect your bag on arrival at JFK because you will need to transport it to LGA

The best mode of transport is probably to take a cab. But that depends on your definition of "best".

Comment: I'm not so familiar with JFK area and will be travelling with kids. So I think the best is to take cab - Thanks really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

> Do I have to claim my checked in luggage at JFK and then recheck it at
>   LGA or will the luggage go straight to my domestic airport?

You'll have to collect it yourself and check it in at LGA; as the airports are about 10 miles apart. Travel time depends on traffic, but it shouldn't take you more than 30 minutes.

A taxi is the most convenient option, but you can also take the train.

One important point to keep in mind is that if your flight from LGA is a domestic one, the baggage allowances will differ from your international inbound flight to JFK; so be warned that you may end up paying extra.

Comment: Assuming that your destination is in the US, then if the domestic flight from LGA is in the same booking as the international one, then the US rules say the baggage allowances on the first flight count for all flights in your booking [link](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/14/399.87). So no worries about paying extra if it's all on one ticket.

Comment: Yeah forgot to mention the majority carrier rule; but that would depend on the OP providing more details about their reservation.

Comment: Yes I booked the tickets as one roundtrip, so the domestic flights are by AA and international by Etihad.

Comment: There is no train service to La Guardia.